# Reading a txt in R with weird header

Tags: r

I am trying to read a txt file in R but always I am getting

```
Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  : 
  line 113 did not have 10 elements
```

I noticed that in the header of my file I have something like

```
 0000775 €   g¿´�€   4_®™00000016125 13404727020 017402  0                                                                                                    ustar   devons01                        stlab-icgc
```

Even by removing these characters I am not able to read this file

This is link of my file

https://www.dropbox.com/s/rpc5jgti5aa433b/txt.txt?dl=0

Could somebody please heap me in reading this file in R?

Comment: Where is the file from, how was it generated? Looks like an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete the corrupt portion preceeding `CFS` in the header and it works with with `read.delim()`.

Comment: Sorry where is the corrupt portion preceeding CFS ?

Comment: Everything before it. Just open it in a text editor.

Comment: @DevonRyan Couldn't it be a different encoding used?

Comment: @llrs No, there was just a bunch of gibberish. It looks like some other content got added to the front of the file.

Comment: Ok, it's simply when I see this question marks I always suspect of wrong encoding...

Answer (score 3):

We can skip the first row:

```
read.delim("txt.txt", skip = 1, header = FALSE)
```

**Or** we can get the *"uncorrupted"* version of the table, it looks like it is from [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.celrep.2013.07.003), [Table S4](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2211124713003501?via%3Dihub#mmc4).